# Which categories of failed HTTP requests should not be retried, based on their associated status codes?

Tags: angular, rest, http, interceptor

I have an API request re-retry interceptor that I've implemented to re-try failed API calls. currently, it retries all the failed API calls. The question is what kind of failed requests should not be retried? for example, an API that returned a 403 HTTP status code should not be re-tried. responses that have HTTP status codes starting with 2 should not also be retried because they already have returned the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a short list of status codes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
3xx is redirected, it should be checked why the redirection happens, so probably better not to retry
4xx should not be retried, because something is wrong with the request.
5xx can be retried, because something is wrong with the server, though better to wait a few mins with it.

Comment: Im retrying 401 requests when the access token expires. 401 are re-tried until the access token is refreshed using the refresh token. Maximum retry count is set to 3. Is it ok to use retry interceptor for this purpose ?

Comment: @NipunaJayawardana For 4xx it is ok if you change the request. Here you change the access token, so it is fine.